# How can I send on Apple Beta Test projects that was created on Xcode 5 but was migrated to Xcode 6?

Tags: iphone, xcode, testflight, beta-testing

I'm trying to send a build to test using the newly released service by apple, to send the build the iTunes Connect  gets perfectly but when trying to release the build to the user test it tells me the following message:

> Apps and apps submitted to the App Store updates must be created with
>   Xcode 5.1.1 or higher, iOS SDK 7 or later.

This project was created on Xcode 5.1.1 but is now edited on Xcode 6.1, I has migrated all classes, libs and XIBs to new reference.

Someone know what I have to the?

Answer (score 0):

When you build your app, check to see if there is "Update to recommended settings" in your build log (and if so, go ahead and do that update).

It looks like this on my machine (with Xcode 6.1):

[image: Update to recommended settings]

Doing this should get rid of the objections that iTunes Connect is having.

Comment: Thanks but My project didn't have any alert to update recommended settings. Have you another idea ?